# Conditions on $K\subseteq [0,1]$ to ensure the uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ where the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]/K$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $[0,1]$ and uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]/K=\{x \in [0,1]~:~x \notin K\}$ for some $K \subseteq [0,1]$. On what conditions on $K$ we can ensure the uniform convergence on $[0,1]$?

I am sure about uniform convergence for a finite set $K=\{k_1,k_2,...,k_m\}$, since $||f_n-f||_\infty=\max\{|f_n(k_1)-f(k_1)|,...,|f_n(k_m)-f(k_m)|,\sup_{[0,1]/K}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\}$,

Also, I can say $f_n$ need not be uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ for an uncountable set $K=[0,1/2]$, But I am not sure about a countable set $K=\{k_1,k_2,...\}$, How to justify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is an infinite set then  there is a sequence $(k_n)$ of **distinct** points in $K$ converging to some point $k$. Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x \neq k_n$ and $f_n(k_n)=1$. Then $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]\setminus K$ but not on $[0,1]$. Hence, a N &S condition for your conclusion is that $K$ is a finite set.

Answer (score 2):

This fails for $K$ infinite unless you make further assumptions on $f_n$.
E.g., consider $f_n(k_j)=1$ for $n \le j$ and $f_n(k_j)=1/(n-j)$ for $n>j$.
(Also $f_n(x)=0$ if $x \ne k_j$ for all $j$.)